# Scrapy CSS selector for HTML element with class containing non alphanumeric char

Tags: python, css, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl a site. I am trying to select an element in the response.

My response object contains HTML that looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Title goes here</title</head>
    <body>
         <!-- lots of stuff I am not interested in -->
         <select class="Gy(t)">
             <!-- elements -->
         </select>
         <!-- lost more stuff of no interest to me -->
    </body>
</html>
```

### My code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # ....
    print (response.selector.css('select.Gy(t)'))
```

I got the folowing exception thrown when I run my code:

```
"Expected selector, got %s" % (peek,))
File "<string>", line None
cssselect.parser.SelectorSyntaxError: Expected selector, got <DELIM '(' at 9>
```

How can I use a selector (preferably a CSS selector) to select this HTML element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can escape the parenthesis on the css selector, so try:

```
response.css('select.Gy\(t\)')
```